# code for redirecting to a page from a link in excel

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel, console-application

I have an application where all my list data is getting exproted to excel. In excel there is a link in a column. On clicking that link it should redirect to a page form excel. Require c# code for that

Comment: "Excel" alone means nothing. What version of Excel? How do you create the Excel workbook?

Comment: its a excel 2010 workbook. Uisng code we create the excel workbook and save the data from list to that.

Comment: Where you need to redirect.?

Comment: i want to redirect it to a sharepoint page